# Преобразование чисел из одной системы счисления в другую

Tags: c, c++

Имеется проблема:

- есть строковое представление числа в системе счисления с основанием X;
- требуется получить: число как int, строковую запись числа в системе счисления с основанием Y;
- формат входной строки - сколько угодно пробелов, запись числа. Другие символы недопустимы и введены не будут.

Желательно использование ф-ций стандартной библиотеки. Возможно использование методов вручную.

Пока мне приходит мысль использовать strtol(), а затем ltoa().

PS: да, этот будет очередной мега-калькулятор :-)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование из одной системы счисления в другую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67714/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если идти по пути наименьшего сопротивления и меньших времязатрат, то я бы взял готовую реализацию atoi и, добавив параметр int radix, пользовался: [atoi.c](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/atoi_8c-source.html), - тут она вполне ничего.

Изменения просты, как валенок: вместо 10 поставить radix, ну и строку допустимых символов буквами до посинения заполнить. Если ввод будет правильный, то и проверять на превышение полномочий не потребуется:3

Ну и строчку с проверкой на пробелы в цикл ткнуть - она уже присутствует, можно даже не писать, а копипастить.

У меня с системами счисления 2, 8 и 16 оно справилось тока давай=)
Обратно, понятное дело, itoa.

Вот... А чем именно strtol-itoa не устраивает?

Comment: <i>А чем именно strtol-itoa не устраивает</i>
всем устраивает :-)
Только вот вопросик возникает - эти strtol, itoa, atoi ведь должны чем-то отличаться. Хотя бы разрядностью аргументов и знаковостью числа. Интересно охватить максимальный диапазон чисел. Т.е., наверное, int64. Но если не получится - int32.

Comment: Стандартные, по крайней мере, в MVC++, 32битные... В 64битности их не замечал.

Comment: Для 64-bit в вычислениях (аналогичных atoi())) используйте unsigned long long.
Обратно в систему счисления Y - накапливайте остатки от деления на Y в стеке, потом опустошайте его в строку (результат). Только сначала минус нарисовать не забудьте.

Comment: Ужо есть atoll(), но есть ли он везде - вопрос.
Ссылки:<p>
http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/stdlib.h/atol.php?alias=atoll<p>
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.bpxbd00/atoll.htm

Comment: Точно знаю, что не везде(