# Преобразование из одной системы счисления в другую

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

При преобразовании десятичного числа в другую систему счисления нужно делить это число на основание системы в которую переводим при этом запоминать остаток от деления, а полученную целую част делить дальше...

В С++ получить остаток отделения можно с помощью "%", а как продолжить вычисления?
Как получить целую часть и разделить ее на основание?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вам легче будет воспользоваться функцией

```
char *  ltoa ( long value, char * buffer, int radix );
```

последним аргументом просто задаете нужную систему счисления, на выходе получаете - строку.
Это, конечно, если такое подходит для Вашей задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Целая часть = a/b

Comment: а ты кэп.....
Я не пойму как это все связать в кучу...

Comment: Кто я? Старенький я, ты со мною по-русски говори.

Comment: Связать в кучу с помощью цикла while(a/b)

Comment: кэп - капитан очевидность(извини если обидел)
Ну а кодом сам разобрался уже... 6 день как никак мучаю задачу...

Comment: да что ты. на что тут обижаться?

Answer (score 1):

[здесь](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.94.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D1.81.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) есть пример программы

Преобразование из десятичной системы в двоичную:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void dv(unsigned);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned x;
  printf("Vvedite chislo > ");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  dv(x);

  getch();
  return 0;
}

void dv(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned mask = 1, i;
  mask <<= sizeof(unsigned) * 8 - 1;
    for(i = 1; i <= sizeof(unsigned) * 8; i++)
    {
      printf("%c", x & mask ? '1' : '0');
      x <<= 1;
      if(!(i % 8))
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```